# basic List View - Find by ID not working

Tags: android, list, android-listview

i am trying to get a list view working in android studio.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    populateListView();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.stand1,container,false);

}

private void populateListView() {
    String[] pair = {"Pair1","Pair2","Pair3","Pair4","Pair5"};

    //build adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.stand1,pair);

    //populate
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Stand1list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

The errors i am getting are

```
    Error:(31, 40) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(Stand1,int,String[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Stand1 cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Stand1 cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Stand1 cannot be converted to Context)


Error:(34, 36) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
```

stand1 is an xml file, Stand1List is the listview id inside the stand1.xml

I know its something simple , but for the life of me i dont know what...

For references Stand1.java is java file which is a fragment inside the activity_main. It is being called by a nav drawer.

**Update:**

Thanks to Jedil Answer, i have it kinda working. However i have gotten an error when i load the fragment saying text view needs an ID. 
I have no put a textview inside the stand1.xml Below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Stand1list">
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tex1"
            />
       </ListView>




</FrameLayout>
```

And now i am getting error

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `populateListView()` too early, because your view isn't created yet.
Try use `populateListView()` in

```
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the ListView as a member variable of the `fragment`:

```
ListView list; // your ListView
```

And instead of passing this to your `ArrayAdapter`, you need to pass `getActivity()`, the host activity's context.

And finally, initialize the listView inside the `onCreateView` method.

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Stand1list);
```

**CODE:**

```
ListView list; // your ListView

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stand1,container,false);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.Stand1list);
    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView(View mView) { 
    String[] pair = {"Pair1","Pair2","Pair3","Pair4","Pair5"};

    //build adapter 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.stand1,pair);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a `fragment` implementation code.

First error is about that `ArrayAdapter` needs `Context` as first argument.
So `this` in that place of code means`fragment` object, but you need `Context` which could be `Activity` so instead of using `this` use `getActivity()` in those places

`ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.stand1,pair);`

and

`ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Stand1list);`

So how code should look like :

```
ListView mList;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stand1,container,false);
    mList = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.Stand1list);
    return root;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {
    String[] pair = {"Pair1","Pair2","Pair3","Pair4","Pair5"};

    //build adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.stand1,pair);

    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

Comment: Code ran but getting errors  when i open the fragment --

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
at com.example.barry.clayscoretracker.Fragments.Stand1.populateListView(Stand1.java:35)

--line 35 is list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Please call populateListView() inside onActivityCreated() method in fragment

Comment: Please see my answer now.

Comment: Thanks Jedil,- But getting error - java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: That's right because `ArrayAdapter` is binding layout TextView to every string from passed array. So you must provide layout with textView. If you want to create more complex layout you could extend `ArrayAdapter` or make it more general with extending `BaseAdapter`

Comment: i.e. you could use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 as an ArrayAdapter argument

Comment: I added a textview inside xml  ---- 
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Stand1list">
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tex1"
            />
       </ListView>
----- . Now getting error --java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView --....

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this instead:

```
View view = null;
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stand1,container,false);
    populateListView(view); 


    return view;

} 

private void populateListView(View mView) { 
    String[] pair = {"Pair1","Pair2","Pair3","Pair4","Pair5"};

    //build adapter 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.stand1,pair);

    //populate 
    ListView list = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.Stand1list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView listview; // define this on class level

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stand1,container,false);
 listview = view.findViewById(R.id.Stand1list);
populateListView();
retur view ;
```

And In `populateListView()` you set adapter in this way

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.stand1,pair);
```